# c# xmldocument get all siblings nodes after a specific one

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, siblings

Let's say I have following xml :

```
<Report>
    <Tablix></Tablix>
    <Textbox Name="TextboxSearchInjection"></Textbox>
    <Textbox></Textbox>
    <Tablix></Tablix>
    <Textbox></Textbox>
    <Textbox Name="TextboxSearchInjectionEnd">
       <Height>1</Height>
    </Textbox>
    <Tablix>
       <Height>1</Height>
    </Tablix>
   <Textbox>
       <Height>2</Height>
    </Textbox>
   <Textbox></Textbox>
   <Tablix>
      <Height>1</Height>
   </Tablix>
   <Textbox>
       <Height>3</Height>
    </Textbox>
</Report>
```

How to get all siblings nodes after `<Textbox Name="TextboxSearchInjectionEnd">` and update value in Height using XmlDocument in c#?
So finally I will receive list of nodes like Textbox and Tablix but starting from node `<Textbox Name="TextboxSearchInjectionEnd">`. I don't want any before.

Comment: Why use the old `XmlDocument` and not the more modern and convenient `XDocument`?

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to remove some tags, now it should be valid xml. Why to use XmlDocument- good question- because all my solution is unfortunatelly based on old technology and to keep consistence I'd like to solve that .

Comment: Do you want to modify the height of the sibling nodes of `<Textbox Name="TextboxSearchInjectionEnd">` or do you also want to update the height of `<Textbox Name="TextboxSearchInjectionEnd">` itself?

Comment: Both +height of Tablix as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could retrieve all succeeding sibling nodes using [`NextSibling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.nextsibling?view=net-5.0). For Example,

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//*[@Name='TextboxSearchInjectionEnd']");
var result = GetAllSucceedingSiblingNodes(node);
```

Where GetAllSucceedingSiblingNodes is defined as

```
IEnumerable<XmlNode> GetAllSucceedingSiblingNodes (XmlNode node)
{
    var currentNode = node.NextSibling; // Use currentNode = node if you want to include searched node
    while(currentNode!=null)
    {
        yield return currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.NextSibling;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Anu for your solution! It works almost great. There is a small issue. I have updated my previous xml example and I have added to one node attribute Name="TextboxSearchInjection". In that case scenario it takes all my nodes. How to fix that?  And yes indeed I need to use var currentNode = node;

Comment: Regarding the glitch you mentioned, could you please verify it using following https://dotnetfiddle.net/w30UMS

Answer (score 0):

Ok Anu I have solution based on your:

```
        private static IEnumerable<XmlNode> GetAllSucceedingSiblingNodes(XmlNode node, XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr)
        {
            var currentNode = node;//.NextSibling; // Use currentNode = node if you want to include searched node
            while (currentNode != null &&
                currentNode.Attributes["Name"].Value != "TextboxSearchInjection")
            {
                yield return currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode.NextSibling;
            }
        }
```

One more time big thank you!

Comment: I do not think you need this 'currentNode.Attributes["Name"].Value != "TextboxSearchInjection")'  here. Could you please check the following https://dotnetfiddle.net/w30UMS

Comment: Unfortunatelly I do need that, otherwise it takes TextboxSearchInjection as well as TextboxSearchInjectionEnd siblings.